# How to install gloobus preview on 12.10?

Tags: nautilus

You look, I have installed the version 12.10 of the Ubuntu and try to install the Gloobus Preview, but when I finished and started to use it, any file was opening with it. The files opened totally no view. What happened? if I wonder because of the new version?

Comment: hmm, as far I know there is no ppa for gloobus previewer for 12.10. How did you install it?

Answer (score 5):

Well, Ubuntu Precise users can install it by simply running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gloobus-dev/gloobus-preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gloobus-preview gloobus-sushi
```

If you want to enable to open LibreOffice or OpenOffice documents with Gloobus Preview, install this additional package:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

If you want to install it offline... you can download the **deb** from the following link
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/gloobus-dev_gloobus_preview/quantal/main/base/gloobus-preview

Comment: after installing it in elementaryos based on precise, I've had trouble actually using it. The space bar just seems to open files instead of opening them in gloobus.

Comment: found the answer here http://www.elementaryupdate.com/2013/04/gloobus-preview-in-elementary.html have to enable the preference in dconf-tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download gloobus-preview and gloobus-sushi deb files from this [link](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/test/+packages)

For me works that way. Cheers